# iMacros to extract google Link

Tags: imacros

I have a query in imacro
I have this code

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE GoogleExtract.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:btnG
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM

SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/a href=\"(.*)\" onmousedown=/)[1];")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Chirag_Guru99\Documents\iMacros\Datasources FILE=GoogleExtractLinks.csv
```

I want to extract all google search results links in one excel file
But right now

I have code which extract only first link